# Gulp не обрабатывает SASS и выдает ошибку

Tags: gulp, sass, gulp-sass

Gulp выдает ошибку:

> PS C:\Users\Admin\Landing\app> gulp sass
>   [20:54:04] Working directory changed to ~\Landing
>   [20:54:05] Using gulpfile ~\Landing\gulpfile.js
>   [20:54:05] Starting 'sass'...
>
> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>   Error: app\sass\main.sass
>   Error: Invalid CSS after "              font-size:50px;": expected "}", was >"{} }"
>          on line 25 of app/sass/main.sass
>
> > > ```
> > >         font-size:50px; {} }
> > > ```
>
> -----------------^
>
> at options.error (C:\Users\Admin\Landing\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)

Код CSS:

```
h2>span{
color:#ff6d6d;
}

p{
font:16px/1.2 'exomedium';
color:#282828;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    h1{
        font-size:50px;
    }

    h2{
        font-size: 30px
    }

    h3{
        font:20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Как предположение: в sass не ставятся точки с запятыми, скобки ... а то что Вы используете - SCSS , возможно стоит попробовать заменить формат main.sass - с `app\sass\main.sass` на `app\sass\main.scss`